# Dificuldade para organizar/estrutura controller no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estou com dificuldades para estruturar o meu controller **ArquivoController**. Principais pontos de dificuldade:

- Select que se repete em diferentes métodos
- Estou restringindo a busca pelo ID do usuário logado, seria mas adequado utilizar policy para está finalidade, se sim, como fazer isso?
- Em alguns pontos utilizo $this->authorize('arquivos', $arq), essa abordagem está correta?

**Obs**: o código fonte do projeto está disponível em: https://github.com/fabiojaniolima/WebUpload

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Painel;
use Auth;
use App\Models\Arquivo;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class ArquivoController extends Controller
{
    private $redirect;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->redirect = '/painel/arquivos';
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $arquivos = Arquivo::join('tags', 'tags.id', '=', 'arquivos.tag_id')
                        ->where('tags.user_id', Auth::id())
                        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                        ->select('arquivos.*')
                        ->paginate(25);
        return view('painel.arquivos.index', compact('arquivos'));
    }

    public function download($id)
    {
        $arq = Arquivo::join('tags', 'tags.id', '=', 'arquivos.tag_id')
                    ->where('arquivos.id', $id)
                    ->first();

        if (!$arq)
            abort(404);

        $this->authorize('arquivos', $arq);
        $caminho = storage_path('app/' . $arq->caminho);
        return response()->download($caminho, str_slug($arq->titulo, '-') . '.' . File::extension($caminho));
    }

    public function detalhes($id)
    {
        $arq = Arquivo::join('tags', 'tags.id', '=', 'arquivos.tag_id')
                    ->where('arquivos.id', $id)
                    ->first();

        if (!$arq)
            abort(404);

        $this->authorize('arquivos', $arq);

        $path_arq = storage_path('app/' . $arq->caminho);

        $info = (object) [
            'id' => $id,
            'titulo' => $arq->titulo,
            'extensao' => File::extension($path_arq),
            'tamanho' => File::size($path_arq),
            'carregado' => $arq->created_at->format('d/m/Y à\s H:i:s'),
            'owner' => $arq->email,
            'tag' => $arq->tag,
            'md5' => hash_file('md5', $path_arq),
            'sha256' => hash_file('sha256', $path_arq)
        ];

        return view('/painel/arquivos/detalhes', compact('info'));
    }

    public function excluir($id)
    {
        $arq = Arquivo::join('tags', 'tags.id', '=', 'arquivos.tag_id')
                    ->where('arquivos.id', $id)
                    ->first();

        if (!$arq)
            abort(404);

        $this->authorize('arquivos', $arq);
        Storage::delete($arq->caminho);
        $arq = Arquivo::find($id);
        $arq->delete();
        return redirect($this->redirect)
                    ->with(['status' => 'success', 'msg' => 'Arquivo excluido!']);
    }
}
```

Comment: uma coisa! na hora de mostrar os arquivos você fez um filtro pelo `tags.user_id` ai tudo certo, mas, nos outros métodos se deveria ter repetido essa `where`, se não acha? (se não fizer qualquer usuário logado pode ver qualquer arquivo!!!)

Comment: Então ta errado Fabio, bom essa é minha opinião.

Comment: Não repeti o filtro pois estou utilizando $this->authorize('arquivos', $arq); o filtro está lá no app\Providers\AuthServiceProvider.php, fiz isso pois o próprio provider já exibe uma página 403 de acesso negado. Não consegui colocar a mesma abordagem no método índex() pois nele não posso negar acesso a página, só impedir a visualização dos registros...